# Referencing Existing Schema in OWL?

Tags: owl

Is it possible to use an existing schema in OWL? In particular, I intend to extend

http://schema.org/Book

with severals attributes but I have no Idea how to start:

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="ExtendedBook">
  ... my additional attributes
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="xxxxxx" /> 
</owl:Class>
```

How can I reference Schema's Book definition instead of the xxxx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly. Is it that you want to import the original ontology, and then extend the Book class? It would go more or less like this:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns="..."
  xmlns:schema="http://schema.org/">

 <owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
   <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://schema.org/"/>
 </owl:Ontology>

  <owl:Class rdf:ID="ExtendedBook">
    ... my additional attributes
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="schema:Book" /> 
  </owl:Class>

</rdf:RDF>
```